# Problems Changing a Div Color with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Okay, so this is what I've got:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>The Down-Champlain Regatta</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="homepage.css"/>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poiret+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="topcontainer">
        <img src="Images/Kim.jpg" id="tom">
        <img src="Images/Kim.jpg" id="zach">

        <div id="head">
            <p id="a">Hello South Burlington. We're the</p>
            <h5>Down Champlain Regatta.</h5>
            <p id="s">And we've got a bold new plan for sailing education on Lake Champlain.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="down">
            <p>check it out</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="container">
        <h5>Here's What We're Doing</h5>
        <p class="beginning">The most important thing in sailing is experience. Read all the books you want - you'll still need time on the water.</p>
        <p>The Down Champlain Regatta is a non-profit organization designed to give students, if nothing else, tons of time on the water. Its three weeks of all-weather keelboat sailing on Lake Champlain, something not offered in many other places, will teach students more than anything else can.</p>
        <p>This course is not for new sailors. It's for kids who know how to sail, but want to take it to the next level. It's for kids who want to move up into the world of keelboat racing.</p>
        <p>And at the end of the course, they do just that. The course finishes with an all-day, student-led race down Lake Champlain. This is a unique opportunity for the students to apply their newly learned skills, build confidence, and get exposure in the racing community. </p>

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#down").mouseover(function(){
                $("#down").animate({backgroundColor: "#1363bf"}, 2000)
            });

            $("#down").mouseout(function(){
                $("#down").animate({backgroundColor: "#e03535"}, 250)
            });

            $("#down").click(function(){
                $("html, body").animate({
                    scrollTop: $("#container").position().bottom+"px"
                }, 800)
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically, there's a div, and I want it to change color when you mouse over it.

See, the problem is .mouseover is detecting both the div AND the paragraph inside it ("check it out"). Thus, when you mouse over the div and the paragraph, it runs through the color change TWICE. Is there any way around this? Perhaps using something other than .mouseover?

Here's the updated code for dwreck08:

```
    $("#down").mouseover(function(){
        $("#down").not("p").animate({backgroundColor: "#1363bf"}, 2000)
    });

    $("#down").mouseout(function(){
        $("#down").not("p").animate({backgroundColor: "#e03535"}, 250)
    });
```

Comment: You use jquery UI, too?

Comment: @nevermind: Yes he is, here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mu2x2088/

Comment: I think this will help you: http://api.jquery.com/stop/ http://jsfiddle.net/mu2x2088/3/?

Comment: Not sure how to do it with CSS except for with #down:hover, but that would be instant with no animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Albin's comment stated, I also suggest using css3 transitions to achieve this. You can still use jquery to toggle it if you like: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mu2x2088/6/)

```
 $("#down").mouseover(function () {
     $("#down").css('background', 'blue');
 });

$("#down").mouseout(function () {
     $("#down").css('background', 'red');
 });


#down {
    transition: 1s;
}
#down:hover {
    transition: 2s;
}
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. I posted my updated code to the answer. Does it look right?